# My Azure Function App is Returning 404 Not Found

Tags: rest, azure-functions

I'm working my way through the book "Mastering Xamarin.Forms" by Ed Snider, which is overall an excellent book. However, I've run into a snag in creating an Azure function app as described in the book. I created the function app (MyTripLogFunctionApp) and a function within it called entry, and I see both of them on portal.azure.com. However, when I try to connect to it from a REST console (I'm using Talend API Tester), I get a 404 error. The URL I'm inputting is, as described in the book, https://mytriplogfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/entry. In Talend API Tester, I set the entry to GET, click on Send, and 404! I've poked around on the web and verified that the version is set to 3, and the function app is set to 64-bit, but no joy. The book is 2 years old, so something may have changed. Anything wrong with how I'm going about this? Here's the code for the entry function:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray entryTableInput,
IAsyncCollector<Entry> entryTableOutput, ILogger log)

{
    //log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    log.LogInformation(req.Method);

if(req.Method == "GET")
{
    return (ActionResult) new OkObjectResult(entryTableInput);
}

var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
var entry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entry>(requestBody);

if(entry != null)
{
    await entryTableOutput.AddAsync(entry);
    return (ActionResult) new OkObjectResult(entry);
}

return new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid entry request.");
}

public class Entry{
    public string Id => Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public double Latitude {get; set;}
    public double Longitude {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public int Rating {get; set;}
public string Notes {get; set;}

public string PartitionKey => "ENTRY";
public string RowKey => Id;
}
```

And here's the json:

```
{


"bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "entryTableOutput",
      "tableName": "entry",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "entryTableOutput",
      "tableName": "entry",
      "take": 50,
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]

,
  "disabled" : false
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code that you created and I downloaded the `Mastering Xamarin.Forms by Ed Snider 2nd Edition eBook` - could you provide me the context/way where Azure Function App is described?

Comment: My copy is the 3rd edition, but where I'm getting hung up is Chapter 6 API Data Access, in the section called Creating an Azure Function. I'll post my code up top in the question.

Comment: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table` NuGet Packages were deprecated. In place of that, `Azure.Storage.Blobs` `Microsoft.Azure.Data.Table` are to be installed and used. Refer [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/).

Comment: Is there a table that has been created in your attached storage account?

Comment: I'm a total noob to Azure, so I'm not sure. If I go to portal.azure.com, and click on either Storage Accounts or SQL Databases on my Home page, there's nothing in either. If I go to my function (entry), and click on Integration, then click on Azure Table Storage (entryTableOutput) under Inputs, I see at the bottom that I have no existing connections available under Storage account connection. So I think you're onto something. But when I click on New to create a Storage account, it tells me that there are no storage accounts in my subscription. So now what?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.